# Creating an active link on a navigation bar while using a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nav

I know there are a lot of questions surrounding this topic online however I cannot get any of the solutions to work for me.I have tried numerous way suggested online. I have a master page with my navigation bar code and I want the active link to be highlighted in green when I am on a particular page of the website. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong or missing to get this to work. I am new to ASP.Net and C# so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my current code in body tags of my master page:

```
         <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = window.location;
            $('.sidebar .nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.sidebar .nav li a').each(function () {
            if (this.href == url) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
            });
          });
        </script>

<form id ="form1" runat="server">
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="green" data-image="../assets/img/side-navship.jpg">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="Default.aspx" class="simple-text">
                Speed-E
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="">
                    <a  href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx") %>">
                        <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                        <p>Home</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/NewCert.aspx") %>">
                        <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
                        <p>New Certificate</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-absolute">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">                        

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyContent"runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 

                </div>                               
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine you have to call your javascript after all the element loaded. have you tried placing your script just above the ending of </body> tag?

Comment: Yes , I just tried that but the green colour still does not display in the sidebar.

Comment: The best work around is to use browser developer console and run your javascript over there and check by putting console.log in between your code